# Feature 'extern local functions' is not available in C# 7.3. Please use language version 9.0 or greater

Tags: c#

how can I fix this error?

```
CS8370: Feature 'extern local functions' is not available in C# 7.3.
Please use language version 9.0 or greater.
```

[image: Visual Studio Project Properties]

I don't know how to switch to version 9.0 in the project and I need help on this issue. Thanks for your valuable time. Have a nice day!!

Comment: Start with the lines where you're getting the messages (show the code). Did you mean to use local functions, or did you make a typo that looks like a local function to the compiler?

Comment: [DllImport("user32.dll")]
            public static extern IntPtr GetMessageExtraInfo();

Comment: and  public static void Main()
 {
     BlockInput(true);
     System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(50000);
     BlockInput(false);
 }

Comment: Don't put it in the comments. [Edit] the post to include all relevant details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wrote in the comment on your question that your code contains the following:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr GetMessageExtraInfo();
```

From the error you are getting it seems that you have put it inside of another function.

This is only allowed in C# language version 9.0 or greater, and according to [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/local-functions#local-function-syntax), the only allowable modifiers for local functions are:

- `async`
- `unsafe`
- `static`
- `extern`

Which means that your code wouldn't work even if you changed the language version to 9.0 unless you removed the `public` modifier.

The easiest solution to your problem is to put `[DllImport]` statements inside of a class, not inside of another function.

Alternative solution if you insist on keeping the function local is to create a .Net (not .Net Framework) project and remove the `public` modifier.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you get *this message* means you already have a compiler that understands the syntax, and the ultimate problem here is that your project is using down-level language version.

This is a safe and reasonable default, but in most cases later language versions work *just fine* - some features won't work, but they'll tell you gracefully. This feature doesn't need any additional services, so you should be able to just edit the csproj to set

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
    <LangVersion>9</LangVersion>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: still i have a same error.